# Reason Trend Micro 11 update disrupts git, svn and other services?

Tags: antivirus

The November 11 2016 Trend Micro AV software client update to version 11 apparently broke a lot of stuff. Personally I lost the use of git and according to our IT department a lot of other stuff broke, too, including:

- Subversion
- Cygwin
- PostgreSQL
- VirtualBox

What was the cause? I guess I don't understand how an AV software can break Git or Subversion. I thought it was just supposed to scan files and report possible malware binaries.

Comment: what do you mean by broke? is it about connection or what?

Comment: @BadrBellaj I don't know that's why I am asking. I assume this is problem that is well known to security experts. Our IT department said that Trend Micro was interferring with server-client communications, but I was hoping for more specific information. The error I get in git is [FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository.] but obviously the errors in SVN or Postgres would be different.

Comment: I think this an issue about SSH/SSL i think it integrates a firewall wich prevent such connection so configure the trendmico builtin firewall to allow such connections or you reinstall git

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the answer, this is a tech support question for this specific product.

Answer (score 1):

AV software integrates itself deeply into the system to be able to check for file creation and modification, executing of programs, loading of libraries and various suspicious behavior. Many AV software also intercepts connections to the internet so they can detect any attacks before they infect the system, i.e. by scanning any mail or web traffic.
Such deep integration can have unwanted side effects like slow down of programs, disability to access the encrypted connection since the AV plays man in the middle etc. And of course might block access to benign resources because they show a behavior which is similar to known bad software. Unfortunately the more you want the AV to protect you (i.e. detect every malware possible, even yet unknown) the more you have to accept such false positives.

Comment: This is a very generic answer. I was hoping for a more specific answer why the November 11 Trend Micro patch broke a whole bunch of client-server tools.

Comment: @TylerDurden: ask TrendMicro then. I think they are the only ones who know the real cause. Given the error message you've added to a comment (instead of the question) it's probably something with intercepting SSL or SSH connections.

Comment: An answer here would be more useful because other people experiencing the same problem would be able to find the information instead of the answer being known to just me.

Comment: @TylerDurden: this is not a support forum for TrendMicro or other products. In fact, TrendMicro has a public support forum which is probably the best place to look for product specific problems.

Comment: This question has applicability to other endpoint AV systems that could potentially behave in a similar. Knowing the exact cause of the problem is relevant to understanding the ways AV can potentially interfere with legitimate desktop apps.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Again, the exact cause of the problem is only known to TrendMicro and might be specific for for this product. A common and product independent source of such problems (AV plays man in the middle) is described in this answer. Also, your question contains several products but no error description apart from "broken". There is a bit more detail in a comment from you but only about git. How the hell should one give a general but still specific answer with such a lack of even the basic error descriptions for most of the problems you mention?

Comment: I am hoping for an answer by someone who is an expert in desktop AV. Presumably this problem is well-known to those who are experts in that area. I am not expecting answer from people who are trying to figure out the problem de novo and have no specific expertise in endpoint AV systems.

Comment: @TylerDurden: I wish you that you'll find one. But even an expert in desktop AV can probably better help with useful error descriptions instead of just "broken".